# Comparar resultado de uma função

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante em JS.
O script abaixo irá fazer calcular os pontos de dois times, que serão informados através do prompt (sim, é chato, mas é pra teste).

Criei (ou tentei) uma função para que sempre fizesse as contas, independente da quantidade de times.

O que eu quero é que, como há dois times, armazene a soma dos pontos de cada time e no final faça a comparação, fazendo com que informe quem está melhor no campeonato.

```js
var meuTime = prompt("Digite o nome do time: ");
var vitoriasMeuTime = prompt("Quantas vitórias seu time tem? ");
var empatesMeuTime  = prompt("Quantos empates seu time tem? ");

var timeAdversario = prompt("Digite o nome do time adversário: ");
var vitoriasAdversario = prompt("Quantas vitórias eles tem? ");
var empatesAdversario  = prompt("Quantos empates eles tem? ");

function calculaPontos (time,vitorias,empates){
var pontos = (vitorias * 3) + parseInt(empates)
document.write(time + " tem " + pontos + " pontos! ");
}

calculaPontos (meuTime, vitoriasMeuTime, vitoriasMeuTime);
calculaPontos (timeAdversario, vitoriasAdversario, empatesAdversario);


 if(pontosMeuTime > pontosAdversario){
 document.write("Estamos melhor que eles!");
} else if (pontosMeuTime == pontosAdversario){
 document.write("Empatados com eles!");
} else {
 document.write("Estamos atrás, vamo logo crl!");
}
```

Comment: O que queres dizer com "armazene a soma dos pontos de cada time"?

Comment: Quando a função for executada na primeira vez, armazenar uma variavel, por ex.: pontosMeuTime = pontos - que seria o resultado da função -.
Na segunda execução deveria acontecer a mesma coisa, e eu criaria pontosAdversario = pontos - resultado da segunda execução -.

Comment: Tens de criar um array que vá somando os resultados de cada momento (um array para cada jogador) e depois somar tudo quando fôr preciso. Como chamas a função que deve dar o resultado final?

Comment: Então.. no caso o exemplo foi com dois times. Agora pensando em arrays, imagino que o ideal seria retornar o resultado da função, como foi feito abaixo, para só no fim ir comparando entre elas. No geral, a ideia desse exemplo foi criar uma função, fixando a ideia de comprimir o código, evitando redundâncias, e também as condições if/else.. De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está calculando o número de pontos, mas não está retornando o valor. Com isso, você terá o valor para atribuir às variáveis `pontosMeuTime` e `pontosAdversario`.

```
var meuTime = prompt("Digite o nome do time: ");
var vitoriasMeuTime = prompt("Quantas vitórias seu time tem? ");
var empatesMeuTime  = prompt("Quantos empates seu time tem? ");

var timeAdversario = prompt("Digite o nome do time adversário: ");
var vitoriasAdversario = prompt("Quantas vitórias eles tem? ");
var empatesAdversario  = prompt("Quantos empates eles tem? ");

function calculaPontos (time,vitorias,empates){
  var pontos = (vitorias * 3) + parseInt(empates)
  document.write(time + " tem " + pontos + " pontos!");
  return pontos;
}

var pontosMeuTime = calculaPontos (meuTime, vitoriasMeuTime, empatesMeuTime);
var pontosAdversario = calculaPontos (timeAdversario, vitoriasAdversario, empatesAdversario);


if(pontosMeuTime > pontosAdversario){
    document.write("Estamos melhor que eles!");
} else if (pontosMeuTime == pontosAdversario){
    document.write("Empatados com eles!");
} else {
    document.write("Estamos atrás, vamo logo crl!");
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc86o7L8/).

Comment: E verdade.. não pensei em retornar o resultado do cálculo. Após retornado, foi só ter criado uma variável que executava a função, e comparar o valor de cada uma? Acredito que tenha entendido! Perfeito! Ah, e obrigado! ;)

Comment: reveja sua função pois testei e os valores inseridos que usei geraram resultados errados, time 1: timão, vitorias(10), empates(0) // time 2: timinho, vitorias(0), empates(1)

Comment: @WilsonRosaGomes, qual o problema? Usei esses valores em https://jsfiddle.net/rmrdmhbd/2/, e não vi problema no resultado.

Comment: testei agora e deu certo, perfeito